# MySQL: combining 2 queries (one empty) using UNION ALL results in error "1048 - Column cannot be NULL"

Tags: mysql

I need to return two different results in a single query. When I run them *independently*, the first returns no rows (that's fine) and the second returns some rows (also fine). When I UNION ALL them, I get `1048 - Column "Date" cannot be null`.

I need resulting rows of `Date, PW, errors` which I will feed a graph to show me what's going on in the system at the points in time specified by `Date`. In both tables, `Date` is of the format `DateTime` and must never be NULL.

```
SELECT `Date`, COUNT(`ID`) AS `PW`, 0 AS `errors`
FROM `systemlogins`
WHERE `Result` = 'PasswordFailure' AND `Date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

UNION ALL

SELECT `Date`,  0 AS `PW`, COUNT(`ID`) AS `errors`
FROM `systemerrors`
WHERE `Date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

GROUP BY ( 4 * HOUR( `Date` ) + FLOOR( MINUTE( `Date` )/15)) --i.e. full 1/4s of hour
ORDER BY ( 4 * HOUR( `Date` ) + FLOOR( MINUTE( `Date` )/15))
```

I have read that MySQL might ignore tables' NOT NULL conditions in UNIONs, causing that error. I have indeed removed the "NOT NULL" restriction on the tables and, tada, it works. Now, those restrictions have been put there for a reason and I would like to keep them while running the aforementioned query - is there any way?

**Edit**:
`Order` is the villain - removing it returns a correct result, albeit with one empty row where `Date` is `NULL`. For my purposes, I need to order the results by `Date` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you selecting the `Date` column? Since you are using a aggregate function `COUNT`, but there is no `GROUP BY` clause in any of the selects, seems to me that you do not care about the `Date` column.

Try adding a `GROUP BY` clause, or removing the `Date` column from the select.

Comment: I am sorry for the oversimplification. You are right, I actually group by a value based on `date` (by quarters of an hour). These groups are the whole point of the UNION. I will update the example.